# C++ reference on deleted objects

Tags: c++, object, reference

I'm learning C++ (coming from iOS) and I want to understand the pointer / reference usage.

Is is correct to work with references on objects when they are deleted? Or will the referenced variable also get deleted?

**Example:**

```
Class Foo {
}

Class Faa{
   asyncCall(&Foo)
}
```

1.

```
// ...
Foo *foo = new Foo();
faa->(asyncCall(&foo);
delete foo;
// ...
```

2.

```
// ...
Foo *foo = new Foo();
Foo& refFoo = foo;
delete foo;

// do something with refFoo
```

Comment: This isn't real code. `Class` is misspelled, and you're missing semicolons.

Comment: ... And parentheses etc...

Comment: This `asyncCall(&Foo)` doesn't mean anything in the context you placed it either.

Answer (score 9):

Since your code samples are gibberish, I'll pose my own:

```
Foo* foo = new Foo();
Foo& ref = *foo;
delete foo;

// Use refFoo
```

This is bad. A reference simply refers to an object created elsewhere. In this example, `*foo` and `ref` are exactly the same object. As soon as you destroy that object, by doing `delete foo;`, `ref` is left dangling. It's referring to an object that doesn't exist any more. Accessing it will result in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

A reference in C++ is not the same as a reference in Java, C#, or other garbage-collected languages: for most practical purposes, you can think of a C++ reference as a pointer that you don't need to dereference<sup>*</sup>. Creating a reference to an object does not prolong its life time. That's why it's no more OK to access a deleted object through a reference than it is to access a deleted object through a second pointer: it is undefined behavior.

---

<sup>*</sup> [References are not pointers, though](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C++%29#Relationship_to_pointers).

Answer (score 1):

Besides the fact that your samples are not even close to proper C++ and none of it would compile, it is never OK to operate on deleted objects

Answer (score 1):

When you delete an object it's gone. Anything that refers to that object (pointer, reference) becomes invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The `&` can either mean a reference (as in the declaration `asyncCall(&Foo)` - you misses the data types for the return value and parameters) or takes the address of (as in `asyncCall(&foo)`).

It would also help to have some code that nearly resembles C++ and better still compiles.